# ERD for airports and routes database

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship

I am making designing a database of airports and how they are linked to each other via route. Idea is simpler version of [openflights](http://www.openflights.org/).

This is my ERD:

[image: ERD]

It has four entities namely: Airport, Route, Airline and Airplane. Relations are as follows: binary relation(departure and destination) between airport and route, Airline serves that route and finally airline has a airplane which is usually used on that route.

I am not sure of validity of entities involved and their relations. It would be nice if someone can point to my mistakes.

Comment: I don't see the connection between the plane and the route. I did an ER model for an airline about 10 years ago and if I recall correctly a route can consist of several legs and each *leg* has a start and end point. But maybe for your use-case you don't need to model the intermediate stops

Comment: What should be the connection between plane and route? I am looking to make a simpler version of a database having the info of airports and routes or links between them as well airlines covering that route so for now I am not considering intermediary stops. However, I do appreciate your kind suggestion and after initial model I will work on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not call this a routing table.

Routes have way points and tracks, which are subject to change. For example, the route from KFJK to KORD is `COATE Q436 EMMMA WYNDE5` (these are waypoints and WYNDE5 is the arrival at O'Hare).

Your diagram is more of a destinations table. Most flights are single leg ("direct") and for multi-leg flights you need to track those separately.

I would track flights (which have a unique number) instead of your "route number" variable. A flight can be flown by different equipment. For example, the same flight can be flown in a 777 or a A380.

Many airlines fly the same *route* but use different *flights*; each flight consists of the following:

1. Unique number
2. Aircraft Type
3. Origin
4. Destination (these can be multiple or intermediate).

The *route flown* is predefined. Have a look at [this table](http://flightaware.com/live/findflight?origin=KJFK&destination=KORD) of flights between Kennedy International and Chicago O'Hare.

If you click on the ident column (this is the flight number), you'll see the route flown for that flight.

I would make the following changes:

1. Remove 'speed' from the aeroplane table; and rename this table to 'equipment'.
2. Rename 'alias' to 'ICAO' and add their ICAO code there (its three letters).
3. Airlines don't have routes; so I would rename routes to 'destinations'.
4. Airports don't have route numbers; so I'm not sure what that is doing there.
5. Airports have two main identifiers, the ICAO identifier code (4-letters) and the IATA identifer (3-letters). I would add both of these.
6. I would rename route number to 'flight number', and then add the actual flight number to it; with each leg entered individually. This will take care of your multi-leg (multi-stop) flights.
7. I would add a flight_equipment table to have a link between each flight, and which equipment is used. Right now there is no link between the flights and the airplanes.

Comment: So what you are suggesting is that i should have following tables:
Flight(UIN,Origin,Destination,Aircraft,Airline)
Equipment(model,type,make,capacity)
Airline(name,Origin,ICAO)
Airport(ICAO,IATA,name,address)
flightequipment(flight,equipment)

This is how I get it but I am amateur and still learning so i appreciate your help. Also can you put some more light on multi leg with respect to my schema. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Several questions come to mind:

- `Route`

  - What are `are_No`, `Dep_air` and `Dest_air`?
  - `no_of_stops`: Is the number really sufficient or do you need the stops?
  - Why is `ends_ad` and `starts_from` and intersection? (hope I've read this right?)
- `airport`

  - Why does it have a `route_No`?
- `Route` < has > `airline`

  - <strike>Is this really `M-M`? Wouldn't each airline operate their own routes even if they use the same airports?</strike>
- `airline`

  - What is `modelNo`?
  - `no_of_planes`: You already got that information implicitly, usually no need to store it again.
  - `aeroplane`: Are these the actual airplanes (e.g. one airline would have several instances of Airbus A380?). If so, an additional table defining the types might make sense.

General:

- Make sure to use consistent naming:

  - Case: `Route` vs `airline`
  - Avoid abbreviations (personal opinion): `Dest_air` vs `destination_airport`
  - Consistent use of underscores: `modelNo` vs `route_No`

**Edit**: Since you decided to ignore intermediary stops, this is what your model could look like:

- airline

  - airline_id (PK)
  - name, alias, ...
- airline_aeroplane

  - airline_aeroplane_id (PK)
  - airline_id (FK)
  - model, make, capacity, ...
- airport

  - airport_id (PK)
  - name, city, country, ...
- route

  - route_id (PK)
  - route_number, number_of_stops, ...
  - departure_airport (FK)
  - destination_airport (FK)
- airline_route

  - airline_id (FK) (PK)
  - route_id (FK) (PK)

Comment: I'm pretty sure `route` to `airline` **is** a M:N relationship. The routes are defined (and allocated) by a national or international aviation association. Multiple airlines can fly the same route.

Comment: First of all I am a newbie, as you can see, so sorry for not following standards. dep_air is supposed to be departure airport and destination_airport for dest_air. What should be the relation between route and airport? Should route connect two different instances of airport and then route linked to airline? Looking for some suggestions to improve.

Comment: @PeterLang Kindly clarify these: I think you missed route_id as PK in route since you used it as FK in airline_route.
Relationship between airport and route.

Comment: `airline_route` doesn't need an artificial PK. As each airline can only use each route once, the PK of that table is `airline_id, route_id`. And I would rename `airline_aeroplane` because the name somehow suggests a M:N relationship (similar to `airline_route`). I would use just `aeroplane` but that is a personal preference I guess.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so you are suggesting "airline_id, route_id" should make a composite primary key for airline_route but individually they also act as FK in the table. 
Can you please comment between the Route and airport relation now with added entity of airline_route.

Comment: I was unsure about that PK, changed it now. I would be fine with both `aeroplane` and `airline_aeroplane`, but I felt like adding that information to the name. Choose whatever you like better.